# Updating changeset through channel. It does not update..

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have table of `Subcategory` and `Category`. `Subcategory` belongs to `Category` and `Category` has many `subcategory`.

In `Category` table, there are `name` and `subcategory`, which is boolean.

What I want to make is that when a user creates a subcategory, it checks whether there are unassigned food (which means a `food` is not assigned to any subcategories) and if there are not any unassigned food, it updates `subcategory` value of `Category` table to `true`.

```
def handle_in("create:subcategory", %{"name" => name, "category_id" => category_id}, socket) do 

 changeset = Subcategory.changeset(%Subcategory{name: name, category_id: String.to_integer(category_id)})
|>Repo.insert()

unassignedfood = from(f in Myapp.Food, where: f.category_id == ^category_id and is_nil(f.subcategory_id), select: map(f, [:id, :name])) |> Repo.all 

 if unassignedfood == nil do
  category = Repo.get!(Myapp.Category, category_id)
 |> Myapp.Category.changeset(%{subcategory: true})
 |> Repo.update!
else
 category = Repo.get!(Myapp.Category, category_id)
 |> Myapp.Category.changeset(%{subcategory: false})
 |> Repo.update 
end

 subcategories = from(p in Myapp.Subcategory, select: map(p, [:id, :name, :category_id])) |> Repo.all
 response = %{subcategories: subcategories}

 broadcast! socket, "subcategories:updated", response

 {:noreply, socket}
end
```

So I made code like above, if there are not unassigned food, change `subcategory` value of `Category` table to `true`.

I checked that there are not `unassignedfood` but it does not update.

Is this right way to do?? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `Repo.all` will never return `nil`. Did you mean to do `unassignedfood == []`?

Comment: oh... i see. What I want to do with `unassignedfood` is that to check if there are `food` without `subcategory_id` or not in one `category_id`... I tried `unassignedfood == []` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Repo.all` returns a list of records, and an empty result would be `[]`, not `nil`, so if you want to check for an empty response, you need to change:

```
if unassignedfood == nil do
```

to

```
if unassignedfood == [] do
```

---

If you only want to check if a record exists, a more efficient way would be to use `Repo.one` with `limit: 1` and `select: true` and then check if it returns true:

```
unassignedfood = from(f in Myapp.Food, where: f.category_id == ^category_id and is_nil(f.subcategory_id), limit: 1, select: true) |> Repo.one

if unassignedfood do
  ...
else
  ...
end
```